# SSO Integration between custom java webapp and drupal

Tags: drupal, tomcat, preprocessor

I have a custom web "portal" that is essentially a webapp built primarily using JSP/Tiles, Spring/MVC, and Hibernate.  It runs on an Apache/Tomcat, MySQL stack.  I have the portal within quotes because this is not truly a portal in the same sense as a Liferay, Glassfish or whatever portal server.  But essentially what looks like a portal to a business user and one that pulls in data from several 3rd party systems through custom system integration.

I am now looking to add a community module to this "portal".  A key piece of this requirement is to federate identity between this "portal" and the community server.  Further, to facilitate a seamless single sign-on from the "portal" to the community.  My preference is to keep the choice of community software to java-based and open source.  Liferay is one example of it.  JForum is another though it is limited to just discussion forums and not other modalities such as blogs and wikis.

Presently, the custom "portal' provides its own authentication/authorization mechanism based on user information in the MySQL database.  It appears that for a scalable and flexible account provisioning across multiple systems, I am better of refactoring this to be based on a CAS-based authentication supported by a directory server such as OpenLDAP.  It seems like with this approach I might be able to integrate with a community server such as Liferay.

If I extend my choice of community server to a PHP-based solution such as Drupal, can I accomplish the same result through a CAS-based approach?  Any recommendations on how to federate identity (and enable SSO) between a custom Java webapp and Drupal?  Entry point (login) for a user to the community will only be through the custom "portal".

Answer (score 0):

CAS is a very popular method. [Here](http://drupal.org/project/cas) is a Drupal module to support SSO into a Drupal installation.